# NSDateFormater strange behaivor

Tags: objective-c

My iPhone 4 with iOS5 and iPhone5 with iOS6 have timezone setting as New York, I would like 
to parse a date string like "Mar 15, 07:25PM EDT", then reformat and display just the time 
like "07:25PM", on iOS5, it always change to EST, then missing an hour when daylight is in 
effect.

The following code will demo this problem.

```
NSDateFormatter* formater= [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formater setDateFormat:@"MMM d, hh:mma z"];
NSDate * date = [NSDate date];
NSString * strDate = [formater stringFromDate:date];
NSLog(@"%@", strDate);
// Output  "Mar 15, 07:25PM EDT" on iPhone5(iOS6) and iPhone4 (iOS5)

date = [formater dateFromString:strDate];
strDate = [formater stringFromDate:date];
NSLog(@"%@", strDate);
// Output Mar 15, 07:25PM EST on iPhone5(iOS6)
// Output Mar 15, 06:25PM EST on iPhone4 (iOS5)
```

I also tried set timezone explicitly with 'EDT', does not help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Change the `timeZoneWithAbbreviation` EST or CDT.

```
NSDate* today = [NSDate date];

NSTimeZone* cSTTimeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"CDT"];
NSTimeZone* destinationTimeZone = [NSTimeZone systemTimeZone];

NSInteger sourceGMTOffset = [cSTTimeZone secondsFromGMTForDate:today];
NSInteger destinationGMTOffset = [destinationTimeZone secondsFromGMTForDate:today];
NSTimeInterval interval = destinationGMTOffset - sourceGMTOffset;
NSDate* destinationDate = [[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeInterval:interval sinceDate:today];
NSDateFormatter* formaters= [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formaters setDateFormat:@"MMM d, hh:mma z"];
NSString * strDates = [formaters stringFromDate:destinationDate];
NSLog(@"%@", strDates);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the locale of the NSDateFormatter before performing the date to string conversions like so:

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
formatter.locale = [NSLocale currentLocale];
```